# Cinerella linux video editor binaries? Can't compile

Tags: video-editing, compile, binary-files

I can't compile Cinerella 4.4.
Last messages I get from the compiler are below.

1) How can fix the compilation? Seems like some GCC or lib incompatibility. I use Ubuntu 12.10.

2) Can I get Cinerella binaries somewhere?

```
gcc -c -fno-implicit-templates -O3 -Wall -DSUPPORT_EDITLINE -I../include -DINSTANTIATE_TEMPLATES siod.cc
In file included from ../include/EST_THash.h:46:0,
        from siod.cc:31:
../include/EST_TIterator.h: In instantiation of ‘EST_TStructIterator<Container, IPointer, Entry>::EST_TStructIterator(const Container&) [with Container = EST_THash<EST_String, EST_Regex*>; IPointer = EST_THash<EST_String, EST_Regex*>::IPointer_s; Entry = EST_Hash_Pair<EST_String, EST_Regex*>]’:
siod.cc:47:3:   required from here
../include/EST_TIterator.h:212:7: error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
../include/EST_TIterator.h:212:7: note: declarations in dependent base ‘EST_TIterator<EST_THash<EST_String, EST_Regex*>, EST_THash<EST_String, EST_Regex*>::IPointer_s, EST_Hash_Pair<EST_String, EST_Regex*> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
../include/EST_TIterator.h:212:7: note: use ‘this->begin’ instead
../include/EST_TIterator.h: In instantiation of ‘EST_TRwStructIterator<Container, IPointer, Entry>::EST_TRwStructIterator(Container&) [with Container = EST_THash<EST_String, EST_Regex*>; IPointer = EST_THash<EST_String, EST_Regex*>::IPointer_s; Entry = EST_Hash_Pair<EST_String, EST_Regex*>]’:
siod.cc:47:3:   required from here
../include/EST_TIterator.h:292:7: error: ‘begin’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
../include/EST_TIterator.h:292:7: note: declarations in dependent base ‘EST_TRwIterator<EST_THash<EST_String, EST_Regex*>, EST_THash<EST_String, EST_Regex*>::IPointer_s, EST_Hash_Pair<EST_String, EST_Regex*> >’ are not found by unqualified lookup
../include/EST_TIterator.h:292:7: note: use ‘this->begin’ instead
make[3]: *** [siod.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [siod] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ondra/sw/vid/cinelerra-4.4/thirdparty/speech_tools'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ondra/sw/vid/cinelerra-4.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I've found the binaries link: http://cinelerra.org/getting_cinelerra.php#ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem here:
http://www.calcmaster.net/cinelerra/forgotten-guide/01-installation/build-compile-cinelerra/

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, please provide all information relative to your answer in your answer as to avoid link rot.